# How can i cofigure a sabai router using a samsung s tablet

Tags: applications, router

Would like to cofigure router settings IP etc but dont have adevice with a LAN connection with me -only my tablet.
Is there any way to do this easily or do l wait?
Thanks

Comment: Its possible, just connect your Samsung device to the router either wirelessely of with cable, then open your browser and  navigate to `192.168.199.1`

Answer (score 0):

You can either connect to the router via WLAN connection or directory via cable i.e LAN with your Samsung tablet

Open a web browser e.g Chrome and enter `192.168.199.1` in the address bar. (Login is admin/sabaipass123.)

You can configure desired settings from this page;

- Navigate to Settings → Static IP
- Edit accordingly

Get more instructions from the [Sabai support page](https://www.my-expat-network.com/guide/sabai-vpn-router-installation)